# why does my swagger-server generate errors?

Tags: node.js, yaml, swagger

I got following errors about the swagger yaml when starting index.js in nodejs-server from "Generate Server" on Swagger Editor.

```
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/2: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/1: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1deleteScenario~1/delete/parameters/0: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1stopScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1restartScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/2: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/1: Missing required property: $ref
  #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Not a valid parameter definition
      #: Missing required property: schema
      #: Missing required property: type
    #/paths/~1botManagement~1startScenario~1/post/parameters/0: Missing required property: $ref
```

yaml file is below.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
  version: 1
  title: I wrote something but can't describe it.
  termOfService: I wrote something but can't describe it.
  contact:
    email: xxxx@xxxx
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
host: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
basePath: /v1
tags:
  - name: I wrote something but can't describe it.
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /XXXXXXXXXX:
    get:
      summary: I wrote something but can't describe it.
      description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              pid:
                type: integer
                format: int64
                example: 0
              name:
                type: string
                example: sample
              pm2_env:
                type: object
                example: {username:sample, windowsHide:true...}
              pm_id:
                type: integer
                format: int64
                example: 0
              monit:
                type: object
                example: {memory:0, cpu:0}
        404:
          description: API not found
        500:
          description: Internal server error

  /xxxxx/xxxxx:
    post:
      summary: I wrote something but can't describe it.
      description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
      parameters:
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              scenario:
                type: string
                example: sample.js
              status:
                type: string
                example: I wrote something but can't describe it.
        400:
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
        404:
          description: "API not found"
        500:
          description: "Internal server error"

  /xxxxx/xxxxx/:
    post:
      summary: I wrote something but can't describe it.
      description:
          I wrote something but can't describe it.
      parameters:
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              scenario:
                type: string
                example: sample.js
              status:
                type: string
                example: I wrote something but can't describe it.
        400:
          description: Bad request
        404:
          description: API not found
        500:
          description: Internal server error

  /xxxxx/xxxxx/:
    post:
      summary: I wrote something but can't describe it.
      description:
          I wrote something but can't describe it.
      parameters:
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              scenario:
                type: string
                example: sample.js
              status:
                type: string
                example: I wrote something but can't describe it.
        400:
          description: Bad request
        404:
          description: API not found
        500:
          description: Internal server error

  /xxxxx/xxxxx/:
    delete:
      summary: I wrote something but can't describe it.
      description:
          I wrote something but can't describe it.
      parameters:
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: xxxxx
          in: formData
          description: I wrote something but can't describe it.
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              scenario:
                type: string
                example: sample.js
              status:
                type: string
                example: I wrote something but can't describe it.
        400:
          description: Bad request
        404:
          description: API not found
        500:
          description: Internal server error
```

It looks the missing property of "$ref".
I know what this property is used. But I don't need any reference to other docs.
In this case, how can I solve this problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition has syntax errors.

1) `version` requires a string value, so it should be `version: '1'`, not `version: 1`. Without quotes `1` is parsed as a number.

2) `example: {username:sample, windowsHide:true...}` is not valid YAML, it should be

```
example:
  username: sample
  windowsHide: true
```

or using JSON syntax:

```
example: {"username": "sample", "windowsHide": true}
```

Same for other inline object examples.

3) Operations that use `in: formData` parameters should specify `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` in the `consumes` keyword:

```
consumes:
  - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

It's hard to say what else might be wrong without seeing your actual definition. You can paste your YAML into https://editor.swagger.io to check for syntax errors, or if your definition has a public URL, use the online validator

```
http://online.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=YOUR_URL
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help!! I solved this problem based on your answer.